# Set-Mailbox AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom powersell command is not working as expected

Tags: c#, powershell, exchange-server

I am looking a way to set AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom for a meetingroom (Mailbox).  I am executing the Exchange 2007 Powershell command using C# code (Windows Application).

Here is my code

```
RunspaceConfiguration rc = RunspaceConfiguration.Create();
PSSnapInException snapEx = null;
PSSnapInInfo info = rc.AddPSSnapIn("Microsoft.Exchange.Management.PowerShell.Admin", out snapEx);
Runspace r = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(rc);
r.Open();
RunspaceInvoke ri = new RunspaceInvoke(r);
string str = "Set-Mailbox -Identity '" + MeetingRoomName + "' -AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom ((Get-Mailbox -identity '" + MeetingRoomName + "').AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom + " + strUser + ")";
ICollection<PSObject> results = ri.Invoke(str);
```

This command is working perfectly from powershell , but not from C# .The code is executing without any error, but the user is not getting added to the list.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could it be that you need to run VS or the C# as Administrator?

Comment: actually I don't have much knowledge on that. Could you please let me know how I can run VS or C# as Administrator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If running as an Administrator is the issue here, try this.

Before you start Visual Studio, right-click on the Visual Studio icon and select run as administrator.

[image: image of how to run as administrator]

If you do that any thing you start with Visual Studio will also "Run as administrator". If you want to run your .exe from the bin directory as administrator, you can right-click on that as well in Windows Explorer and choose "Run as administrator".

Comment: Your post helped me. Now I am able to run the code without any error. Now the issue is comamnd is executing but the user name is not getting added to AcceptMessagesOnlyFrom  list of the mailbox. Could anyone help me to fix this issue?

Comment: I'm not too familiar with Exchange administration. I would suggest creating a new question (maybe even try serverfault.com).